# how to size an svg placed as img?

Tags: svg

I'm using an svg placed as an img, but it appears huge in my browser.

I added a height and width to the tag, but then it appears small. When I inspect it, I can see the box as the size I specified, but the logo is much smaller inside it.

How do you correctly specify a size for svg?

Here's the code `<img src="<images/logo.svg" alt="logo"/>`

I had it as `<img width="558" height="58" src="<images/logo.svg" alt="logo"/>` but the width and height came out smaller in the browser. Without them, it took up the whole area and was huge.

Comment: Does the SVG have a `viewBox` attribute set?

Comment: It all really depends on the SVG contents, can you post an example?

Comment: I edited to add the code.